# ReactJs: react router 6 multiple layouts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a simple application that contains only 4 modules `login/registration`, `accounts`, `account-types` & `websites`. I have created 2 modules for `auth` and `layout`.

All of the authenticated modules are sharing the `<Layout />` layout.

```
...

<Route path="/" element={<Auth />}>
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('auth')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('register')} />
</Route>

<Route path="/accounts" element={<Layout />}>
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accounts')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountCreate')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountEdit')} />
</Route>

<Route path="/account-types" element={<Layout />}>
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypes')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypeCreate')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypeEdit')} />
</Route>

<Route path="/websites" element={<Layout />}>
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('websites')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('websiteCreate')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('websiteEdit')} />
</Route>
...
```

Can this code be shortened, something like this:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Auth />}>
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('auth')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('register')} />
</Route>

<Route path={["/accounts", "/account-types", "/websites"]} element={<Layout />}>
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accounts')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountCreate')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountEdit')} />

  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypes')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypeCreate')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypeEdit')} />

  <Route {...routes.getRoute('websites')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('websiteCreate')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('websiteEdit')} />
</Route>
```

I tried doing it the following way, but received a lot of errors in return:

```js
{["/accounts", "/account-types", "/websites"].map(path => (
  <Route path={path} element={<Layout />}>
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accounts')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountCreate')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountEdit')} />

    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypes')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypeCreate')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypeEdit')} />

    <Route {...routes.getRoute('websites')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('websiteCreate')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('websiteEdit')} />
  </Route>
))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Route` path takes only a string path value, so passing an array of string paths is invalid. If all you are really trying to accomplish is to remove the duplicated `Layout` component rendering you can split the `Layout` layout route from the sub-route paths. Render a single `Layout` layout route, and render nested layout routes for each of `"/accounts"`, `/account-types"`, and `"/websites"`.

Example:

```
...

<Route path="/" element={<Auth />}>
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('auth')} />
  <Route {...routes.getRoute('register')} />
</Route>

<Route element={<Layout />}>
  <Route path="/accounts">
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accounts')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountCreate')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountEdit')} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/account-types">
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypes')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypeCreate')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('accountTypeEdit')} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/websites">
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('websites')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('websiteCreate')} />
    <Route {...routes.getRoute('websiteEdit')} />
  </Route>
</Route>
...
```

If you are trying to further reduce code "clutter" then you might also refactor the code to map the nested routes.

```
const renderRoute = (routeKey) => (
  <Route key={routeKey} {...routes.getRoute(routeKey)} />
);
const renderRoutes = routes => routes.map(renderRoute);
```

```
...

<Route path="/" element={<Auth />}>
  {renderRoutes(["auth", "register"])}
</Route>

<Route element={<Layout />}>
  <Route path="/accounts">
    {renderRoutes(["accounts", "accountCreate", "accountEdit"])}
  </Route>
  <Route path="/account-types">
    {renderRoutes(["accountTypes", "accountTypeCreate", "accountAccountEdit"])}
  </Route>
  <Route path="/websites">
    {renderRoutes(["websites", "websiteCreate", "websiteEdit"])}
  </Route>
</Route>
...
```